# API returns an error with a wrong API path

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following JavaScript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#customers .js-delete").on("click", function () {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this customer?")) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "api/customers/" + $(this).attr("data-customer-id"),
        method: "DELETE",
        success: function () {
          console.log("Success");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

When I run it, I receive the following error in the console:

```
jquery-3.5.1.js:10099 DELETE https://localhost:44367/Customers/api/customers/5 404
```

The issue is the API call should look like `https://localhost:44367/api/customers/5`.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Is your page running at `localhost:44367/Customers`? The  fetch call is relative to the current location

Comment: set the url in ajax request with backslash  as `url: "/api/customers/" + $(this).attr("data-customer-id"), ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is taking relative path. Only add '/' in the beginning of your url.

```
url: "/api/customers/" + $(this).attr("data-customer-id"),
```

It should take you to https://localhost:44367/api/customers/5 instead of https://localhost:44367/Customers/api/customers/5